# Is it possible to generate DataFrame rows from the context of a Spark Worker?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

The fundamental problem is attempting to use spark to generate data but then work with the data internally. I.e., I have a program that does a thing, and it generates "rows" of data - can I leverage Spark to parallelize that work across the worker nodes, and have them each contribute back to the underlying store?

The reason I want to use Spark is that seems to be a very popular framework, and I know this request is a little outside of the defined range of functions Spark should offer. However, the alternatives of MapReduce or Storm are dreadfully old and there isn't much support anymore.

I have a feeling there has to be a way to do this, has anyone tried to utilize Spark in this way?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I don't think adopting Spark just because it's popular is the right decision. Also, it's not obvious from the question why this problem would require a framework for distributed data processing (that comes along with a significant coordination overhead).

The key consideration should be how you are going to process the generated data in the next step. If it's all about dumping it immediately into a data store I would really discourage using Spark, especially if you don't have the necessary infrastructure (Spark cluster) at hand.

Instead, write a simple program that generates the data. Then run it on a modern resource scheduler such as Kubernetes and scale it out and run as many instances of it as necessary.

If you absolutely want to use Spark for this (and unnecessarily burn resources), it's not difficult. Create a distributed "seed" dataset / stream and simply `flatMap` that. Using `flatMap` you can generate as many new rows for each seed input row as you like (obviously limited by the available memory).